# How to check if an issue has no labels in a Github workflow

Tags: github-actions

Right now I'm trying to write a workflow for Github Actions where any issue without any labels is closed automatically.

For the closing part, I already have found https://github.com/marketplace/actions/close-issue

But I'm struggling to find any way to check if github.event.issue.labels is empty. Even if I search for "github workflow check array empty", nothing turns up.

Does anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution by checking for `join(github.event.issue.labels) == ''`.

Comment: There's no current length expression within github actions. The solution you provided seems to be the cleanest one. If more complex traver sing is desired, I would suggest using a step to do all your scripting, then set the output to a variable for next step usage.